# Store multiple ordinary differential equations outputs using StepHandlers with classical runge-kutta integrator

Tags: java, save, ode

I am quite new to java and I am having some issue in understanding how to store the data of multiple solutions of ordinary differential equations.
I am using a classical Runge-Kutta integrator to integrate a trajectory and I need to store all the trajectory history step by step. I have seen in other questions that it is possible to store the data using a StepHandler as follows:

```
StepHandler stepHandler = new StepHandler() {
    public void init(double t0, double[] y0, double t) {}
    public void handleStep(StepInterpolator interpolator, boolean isLast) {
        double   t = interpolator.getCurrentTime();
        double[] y = interpolator.getInterpolatedState();
        output.add(new double[] {t, y[0], y[1], y[2], y[3], y[4], y[5], y[6], y[7]});
    }
};
```

So that at each step I am adding to the *output* variable a list with the data I need. However, this works only if I have to store the data of a single integration.

The problem I have is that I have to run multiple ode integrations and for everyone of them I need to store the data in the way described above. I was thinking of creating an ArrayList of ArrayList and store the integration history of each integration separately as follows:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<double[]>> integrationsOutputs = new ArrayList<ArrayList<double[]>>();
private void propagate() {
    // initialise arraylist to store results locally
    ArrayList<double[]> outputLocal = new ArrayList<double[]>();
    double[] y = new double[8];
    // defining the integrator
    FirstOrderIntegrator integrator = new ClassicalRungeKuttaIntegrator(0.5);
    // setting the differential equations
    FirstOrderDifferentialEquations ode = new models.EquationsOfMotion();
    // adding event handler
    integrator.addStepHandler(stepHandler);
    // integrate
    integrator.integrate(ode, t0, y0, tf, y);
    integrationsOutputs.add(outputLocal);   
}
```

The problem is that I cannot make the StepHandler "see" the *outputLocal* ArrayList I created in order to store the result of one integration. Is it possible to modify the StepHandler to pass it the *outputLocal* variable so that I can actually store the data I want?

Thanks in advance for the help.

**Update**

Using some of the suggestions from LutzL I managed to make it work. I could not directly apply the solution of LutzL as I could not use setTape() method. I had to implement the StepHandler interface into my own step handler and add the method to it as follows:

```
public class MyStepHandler implements StepHandler {
    ArrayList<double[]> _tape;
    public void setTape(ArrayList<double[]> tape) { _tape = tape; }
    @Override
    public void handleStep(StepInterpolator interpolator, boolean isLast) {
        double   t = interpolator.getCurrentTime();
        double[] y = interpolator.getInterpolatedState();
        _tape.add(new double[] {t, y[0], y[1], y[2], y[3], y[4], y[5], y[6], y[7]});

    }
    @Override
    public void init(double t0, double[] y0, double t) {}
}
```

Comment: You could use a derived class of `StepHandler` that takes the list of output tapes as input of the constructor and has an additional method to change the tape.

Comment: Or you could just append the local tape to the global list of tapes after the integration.

Comment: @LutzL: the first option you proposed is exactly the one I was thinking but I  haven't been able to implement it yet as I am not so familiar with Java derived classes (but I am trying). Instead, I am not sure I understand the second option, as my problem is that, in the way the code is now, the StepHandler cannot use the local tape.

Comment: Where does the StepHander get its tape `output` from? Make it a field of StepHandler and add a method `setTape` or `setOutput`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your code snippets how the overall loop over the initial points is constructed. In general, the logic could look like this

- Initialize integrator and stepHandler,
- Loop over initial points `(t0,y0)`:

  - allocate a new tape `localTape`
  - pass this tape to the stepHandler, `stepHandler.setTape(localTape)
  - integrate the ODE
  - append localTape to the global tape collection

As the tape is passed by reference, the updated tape in the step handler is still the same localTape after integration, so it is not necessary to pass it back. So you just have to extend your stepHandler to

```
StepHandler stepHandler = new StepHandler() {
    List<double[]> _tape;
    public void setTape(List<double[]> tape) { _tape = tape; }
    public void init(double t0, double[] y0, double t) {}
    public void handleStep(StepInterpolator interpolator, boolean isLast) {
        double   t = interpolator.getCurrentTime();
        double[] y = interpolator.getInterpolatedState();
        _tape.add(new double[] {t, y[0], y[1], y[2], y[3], y[4], y[5], y[6], y[7]});
}
```

};

Comment: sorry if the question was not perfectly clear. Thanks for the advices. I managed to make it work but I had to implement the StepHandler interface into my own class for the step handler in order to use it. I have updated my question with the step handler I used.